Grouping sets of 4 bits into nybbles in C printf
C23 added support for binary literals (0xb10100110) and for grouping them for human readability using a separator character ('). This is great for input, but how does one change the printf grouping to sets of four bits (a hexadecimal "digit") instead of three bits (an octal digit)?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
  unsigned long long int i =
    0b0001'0001'0010'0010'0001'0000'1111'0100'1011'0001'0110'1100'0001'1100'1011'0001;
  printf("binary: %'#0*llb\n", (int)sizeof(i)*8, i); 
  return 0;
}

I would like the output to look like this:
0b0001'0001'0010'0010'0001'0000'1111'0100'1011'0001'0110'1100'0001'1100'1011'0001

not like this:
0b1,000,100,100,010,000,100,001,111,010,010,110,001,011,011,000,001,110,010,110,001


Btw. that's a GNU extension and not a C23 feature.

Looks like you want to change the .grouping of the locale from 3 to 4.

Neither of the versions are readable no matter what you do. This is why there was so much hesitation to include binary in the C standard to begin with. Hex however would be perfectly readable.

@cremno, nope, it's a C23 addition.  You can read it in section 6.4.4.1 of ISO-IEC-C-9899-DRAFT-N3096-apr-2023.  Personally, I prefer the Java _ approach, which is more readable.  But this is C.

@LuisColorado: I'm not talking about integer constants. The ' printf flag isn't a C23 feature.

THE PO is asking about the C23 tick marks that can be interspersed between digits in an int literal for grouping and readability purposes.  This is a C23 feature.  The PO is confusing this with the printf(3) of grouping digits in output which is a locale feature, and has no relationship with the tick marks used in the integer literals for readability. Of course you can be talking about anything else, I'm not here to discuss that, but the grouping marks to group integer literals is INDEED a C23 feature (cf. 6.4.4.1)  If you look at the output, you will see that there are not tick marks in...

... printf() output, but commas , instead, which is the normal grouping character in Italy FOR MONETARY output.

Probably not the answer you are looking for but did you consider this:
#define number 0b0001'0001'0010'0010'0001'0000'1111'0100'1011'0001'0110'1100'0001'1100'1011'0001

unsigned long long int i = number;
puts(STR(number));

Where STR is your average stringification macro:
#define STR_(s) #s
#define STR(s) STR_(s)

Now why does this make sense? Because ' is there solely for the benefit of the programmer. It is not for the compiler, not for the program and not for the end user. So since you then by definition already have a binary literal in your source for sure, why not simply print that one?

No, not the answer that would solve my problem. As you guessed, I do not want to print constants. Still, here's an upvote for being technically correct.

Alas, Programmatically changing [stuff] with C setlocale() is possible, but requires modification of system resources. Boo.
So you are stuck writing code to do this yourself. Fortunately, it is very easy:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

size_t format_binary_required_size( size_t nbits )
{
    return nbits ? (nbits + (nbits-1)/4 + 3) : 4;
}

char * format_binary( char * s, size_t n, unsigned long long int value )
{
    static const char * digits = "01";
    s[--n] = 0;
    int sep = -1;
    while (n --> 2)
    {
        if (sep++ == 3)
        {
            sep = 0;
            s[n--] = '\'';
        }
        s[n] = digits[value & 1];
        value >>= 1;
    }
    s[  n] = 'b';
    s[--n] = '0';
    return s;
}

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
  unsigned long long int i =
    0b0001'0001'0010'0010'0001'0000'1111'0100'1011'0001'0110'1100'0001'1100'1011'0001;
  //printf("binary: %'#0*llb\n", (int)sizeof(i)*8, i); 
  size_t n = format_binary_required_size(sizeof(i)*8);
  char s[n];
  printf("binary: %s\n", format_binary(s,n,i));
  return 0;
}

Compile with C23 to make that binary literal work, but the code will otherwise work with older standards. Modify it as per your needs.
Oh, for documentation sake, the formatting function takes a string buffer to use, which must be n characters long, where 4 ≤ n. The formatted binary value will fill the string entirely, prefixing it with “0b” and properly terminating it with a nul byte.
Use the first function if you wish to know how big the string must be in order to output N bits. The result will always be for a minimum of 1 bit, even if nbits is zero.

Digit grouping is not a standard feature in the printf family of functions in Standard C. It is a POSIX extension supported by the GNU libc and other unix libraries. It applies to decimal integer conversions (%i, %d and %u) and the integral portion of floating point conversions (%f, %g and %G).
The number of digits in each group cannot be specified on an conversion basis nor depending on the base or the group number, it is specified in the locale.
The thousands separator is specified in the locale as well as the decimal separator that will be used for floating point conversions.  The purpose is the conversion of currency amounts consistent with the local culture. Note that in some cases, the number of digits is not the same for each group, so this feature is only half-baked.
This feature does not meet your goal as it does not apply to hexadecimal or binary conversions and modifying the locale definition is risky anyway.
Here is a simple function to format integers in different bases where you can specify both the grouping number and the separator.
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Convert an integer with parameterized grouping
 * return -1 if base is invalid
 * returns the length of the output without truncation
 */
int format_ull(char *dest,              /* destination array */
               size_t size,             /* array length */
               unsigned long long n,    /* value to convert */
               int base,                /* output radix, 0 or 2..36 */
               int mindigits,           /* minimum number of digits */
               int grouping,            /* group length, 0 for no groups */
               int sep)                 /* separator character */
{
    char buf[sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT];
    char *p = buf + sizeof(buf);
    const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int ndigits, nzeroes, phase;
    size_t pos, len;

    if (base < 2 || base > 36) {
        if (base == 0)
            base = 10;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    while (n) {
        *--p = digits[n % (unsigned)base];
        n = n / (unsigned)base;
    }
    ndigits = buf + sizeof(buf) - p;
    nzeroes = mindigits > ndigits ? mindigits - ndigits : 0;
    ndigits += nzeroes;
    if (grouping <= 0 || ndigits <= grouping) {
        len = phase = ndigits;
    } else {
        phase = (ndigits + grouping - 1) % grouping + 1;
        len = ndigits + (ndigits - 1) / grouping;
    }
    if (size > 0) {
        size--;
        if (size > len)
            size = len;
        for (pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {
            if (phase-- > 0) {
                dest[pos] = (char)((nzeroes-- > 0) ? '0' : *p++);
            } else {
                phase = grouping;
                dest[pos] = (char)sep;
            }
        }
        dest[pos] = '\0';
    }
    return (int)len;
}

#define TEST(n)  test(n, #n)
void test(unsigned long long n, const char *source) {
    char buf[100];
    int nbits = sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT;
    int len;
    printf("source:    %s\n", source);
    printf("normal:    %llu\n", n);
    format_ull(buf, sizeof buf, n, 10, 1, 3, ',');
    printf("base 10/3: %s\n", buf);
    len = format_ull(buf, sizeof buf, n, 8, 1, 3, '\'');
    printf("base 8/3:  %.*s%s\n", (*buf != '0') * (1 + (len % 4 == 3)), "0'", buf);
    format_ull(buf, sizeof buf, n, 16, nbits / 4, 4, '\'');
    printf("base 16/4: 0x%s\n", buf);
    format_ull(buf, sizeof buf, n, 2, nbits, 8, '\'');
    printf("base 2/8:  0b%s\n", buf);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    TEST(0);
    TEST(ULLONG_MAX);
    TEST(0b0001'0001'0010'0010'0001'0000'1111'0100'1011'0001'0110'1100'0001'1100'1011'0001);
    return 0;
}

Output:
source:    0
normal:    0
base 10/3: 0
base 8/3:  0
base 16/4: 0x0000'0000'0000'0000
base 2/8:  0b00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000'00000000

source:    ULLONG_MAX
normal:    18446744073709551615
base 10/3: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
base 8/3:  01'777'777'777'777'777'777'777
base 16/4: 0xffff'ffff'ffff'ffff
base 2/8:  0b11111111'11111111'11111111'11111111'11111111'11111111'11111111'11111111

source:    0b0001'0001'0010'0010'0001'0000'1111'0100'1011'0001'0110'1100'0001'1100'1011'0001
normal:    1234567890987654321
base 10/3: 1,234,567,890,987,654,321
base 8/3:  0'104'420'417'226'133'016'261
base 16/4: 0x1122'10f4'b16c'1cb1
base 2/8:  0b00010001'00100010'00010000'11110100'10110001'01101100'00011100'10110001


Oh, I had thought digit grouping was part of POSIX. Is it not? If it is just a GNU extension, maybe I should go full GNU and call register_printf_function so I can use %B to print formatted binary.

@hackerb9: you are correct, the ' flag is specified in the Single UNIX Specification

@hackerb9: register_printf_function OTOH is a GNU extension and it seems you can redefine the behavior of standard conversions: %#B performs a binary conversion with a 0B prefix for non zero arguments, probably not a problem for you.

The locale specifies how numbers are printed.  But this is used for monetary info normally, and the characters used (in your case , commas) is the locale definition (as the number of digits in a group) are defined and fixed for the locale you use.
The use of tick marks ('), to separate digit groups (which can be done based on your preference to add clarity to the program listing) is some unrelated feature of the C language to make more readable the program listings.... and so, applies only to the source code.  One is for your best reading, the other is mandated by the locale for printing monetary info (some locales use spaces, others use commas and other use tick marks, but that is fixed by the locale definition)
printf() is a library function, so it's implementation can be (or not) coherent with earlier standards, and the formatting of source code is not related on how it implements the printing of numbers.
As you have been told in some of the comments, the group separator character (you use , in your locale) and the positions of it (each three decimal digits) doesn't apply well to the feature you want to reproduce, more by the fact that the ticks in the source are there for your convenience, you are free to group the digits the way you prefer (e.g. D. Knuth in his constants listing from "The art of computer programming" uses groups of three digits before the decimal point, but groups of five after it. e.g. 1,000 * PI = 3,141.59265 35897 93238 46264 33832 79502 8841)
If you read the standard definition (cf. 6.4.4.1) you will see that this is for the programmer convenience, to add readability, and ignored by the compiler.

Here's a proposal I wrote for how to best use C23 digit separators in engineering: Where to place digit separators in C23? Donald Knuth ought to study engineering notation I guess :)

Donald knuth is a teacher of mathematics in Stanford U.  He is the author of TeX, and many other things... he is also honoured with Turing's price.  He even has a pipe organ at home (he made it himself)

Good for him! Did he also create a rationale for why to use 5 digits when all engineers use 3? Given that engineering notation is based on multiples of 10^-3, 10^-6, 10^-9 and so on. Milli, micro, nano.

you cannot use it with floating point numbers, only with integer literals: I am afraid you are mistaken: n3096 specifies in 6.4.4.2 Floating constants that a digit-sequence: is either digit or digit-sequence ’opt digit so you can use ' separators in both parts of the mantissa and in the exponent.

You are right... sorry for the mistake.  Thanks for the hint.  Answer corrected.

Thank you. I understand now that C23 says nothing about output formatting with separators, which is too bad. I used setlocale and the POSIX ' modifier to printf because it is an example of one way to add grouping. I had hoped there was either a C23 or POSIX solution for easily printing numbers with different groupings, but it appears not.

you can easily make a function to print pretty printed binary data.
